# Reload same page after form subit in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, post, submit, selection

I am using a get method to select options with years and months. The URL after submitting this selection looks as follows:

```
www.mywebsite.com/transactions/?yr=2013&mo=6
```

I can reload this page and the selection is still there. However, when i submit a form to add a record, the page reloads as follows:

```
www.mywebsite.com/transactions/?#
```

And the selection is gone. How can I keep the seletion and reload the exact same url after submitting the form?

I am using the following code:

```
<form action="?" method="post">
<SELECT options with different inputs>
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

In my PHP it looks the following:

```
header('Location: ?yr='. $GLOBALS['yearselect'] .'&mo=' . $GLOBALS['monthselect']);
```

It creates the right URL after submit, only the global variables are not updated. I defined those as follows:

```
$GLOBALS['monthselect'] = date('m');
$GLOBALS['yearselect'] = date('Y');
```

And they are changed when I select an option.

Comment: Something in your code is redirecting to that new URL. And since my crystal ball is broken and you're not showing the relevant code - I have no idea what is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could traverse through submitted variables and add them to the HTML code.

```
<form action="target.php?var1=<?= $_GET["value2"]; ?>&var2=value2" method="get">
```

Or just use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` inside `action=""`.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code, after you get the values by GET method, use the header() function as :

```
header("Location: www.mywebsite.com/transactions/?yr=2013&mo=6");
```

It will redirect to the page with the form.

EDITED:

This is a sample code for your need:

```
<?php

$years=array(1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004);

if(isset($_POST['year']))
{

/*

Do your coding here


*/

echo <<<EOT
<form action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}' method='POST'>
<select name='year'>
EOT;

    for($i=0;$i<6;$i++)
    {
        if($years[$i]==$_POST['year'])
            echo "<option value='{$years[$i]}' selected='selected' >{$years[$i]}</option>";
        else
            echo "<option value='{$years[$i]}'>{$years[$i]}</option>";
    }

echo <<<EOT
</select>
<input type='submit' value='Add'>
</form>
EOT;
}
else
{
echo <<<EOT
<form action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}' method='POST'>
<select name='year'>
EOT;

    for($i=0;$i<6;$i++)
    {
            echo "<option value='{$years[$i]}'>{$years[$i]}</option>";
    }

echo <<<EOT
</select>
<input type='submit' value='Add'>
</form>
EOT;
}

?>
```

It will print the first value of the drop-down list on the first time, and after that it'll save the values.

Comment: i want it to redirect to the current page. setting this makes no sense, it has to be variable. Check my post, I added what I tried.

Comment: i think that i didn't quite understood your need...
so i've edited my answer, you can see if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your form element probably has an attribute action="#".
You could replace this with the original request uri (assuming you use the POST method, if you use GET the query parameters in the form's action attribute will be overridden in most browsers.

`<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>">your form</form>`

Answer (score -1):

Inside form tag action attribute should b set to the page which handles your request,i think u have set  action='#' .
Please specify more detail.so that i can help u

Comment: I think this should be a comment, not an answer.